# Unit ExtActns was compiled with a different version of UrlMin.IBindStatusCallBack?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am getting this message now :

"Unit ExtActns was compiled with a different version of UrlMin.IBindStatusCallBack"

when i try to compile two old projects of mine in Delphi 7 on a new machine:

I have checked and double checked that the library paths are indentical on the current machine they are compiling on and the new machine i have set up.

Anyone know what is going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it must have been an issue with Rad Studio 2010 installed. I uninstalled it, cleaned the registry and system variable paths of all instances of Rad Studio.......and everything compiles fine now!

Answer (score 2):

What that usually means is that there's something in UrlMin.dcu that's not compatible with ExtActns, but the compiler can't find UrlMin.pas to recompile it.  Check your IDE paths to make sure it can find the UrlMin unit.

Comment: WHat is UrlMin?  I did a search of my entire Delphi directory and found no file with that name.

Comment: @Shane: I have no idea.  I just know what that error message means in general.

Comment: @ Mason:  I dont understand your answer. Do you have UrlMin on your machine? Are you using Delphi 7?  Cause its not part of my Delphi 7 Enterprise Install.  Im not sure why people are liking this answer, cause it seems to be wrong on all accounts if you ask me!

Comment: @Shane: I have no idea what UrlMin is. This has nothing to do with UrlMin or Delphi 7 Enterprise. It has to do with the compiler not being able to link one DCU to another, and not being able to find a PAS file to rebuild the DCU. That's what `Unit X was compiled with a different version of Y.Z` means in the general case.